# NSLocalizedString with variables doesnt work for me

Tags: string, swift, variables, localization, nslocalizedstring

so i have the following code:

GameScene:

```
Rule = Level / 10
let StrRule = String(Rule) //for example Level = 24 -> Rule = 2

let RegelString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("RegelText", comment: ""), StrRule)

//Give the String out in an UILabel as text
RegelLabel.text = RegelString
```

Thats how my Localizable.strings looks like:

```
"RegelText" = "You lose %d goals if you miss.";
```

So i start the game and my `Level` is 24. So `Rule` should be 2.

So i build and run but when i start the App he shows me some crazy numbers.
The Label is like: `You lose 1314063968 goals if you miss.`

Why it doesnt work?

Comment: Do you know what the %d format is for? And what type has the argument that you pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is for numbers. `StrRule` is obviously not a number. Are you intending to use `%s`? `RegelText` should be like this:

```
"RegelText" = "You lose %s goals if you miss.";
```

Or just use `Rule` and not convert it into a string. The code could be like this:

```
Rule = Level / 10
let RegelString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("RegelText", comment: ""), Rule)
```

In this case `RegelText` would still use `%d`.

In addition, I don't see that you rounded the result of `Level / 10`. I know that dividing an integer by an integer results in an integer, not a decimal. But to be on the safe side I think you should put the `Level / 10` in a `round` or `floor` function.

Comment: Thank you. I thought its always `%d`. I have one more problem now .. what you said helped, its showing me now for exampe `You lose 1 goal if you miss.` I have another label where it shows the Speed in %. My Localizable.strings is `Your average Speed: %d %` and my GameScene is `let mySpeedString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("SpeedText", comment: ""), Speed)`. Now if I build and run it shows `Your average Speed: 100` but without the % in the String.

Comment: @aignetti When it displays "you lose 1 goal...", what is the level value? Also, the issue with the "your average speed: %d %" is that when you want a percent sign you can't just type "%", you have to escape it, like this "%%".

Comment: Level can be 0-100, but that works fine. Thank you a lot. `%%` helped too. Now everything works. Thank you 100 times Blip. :-) It shows now `You lose 1 goal if you miss.` and `Your average Speed: 100 %`. Great, thank you !

Comment: Yeah, anytime! :) I thought the number in "you lose 1 goal" is wrong so I asked you what is the level value to try to debunk it. But yeah, you're welcome 100 times anytime :)